# ListView Using BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout

Sir i am writing a code for listview from my sqlite database using BaseAdapter. I searched a lot but can not find any code like i write. so please help me.
I have a table MONEY it have four field ID, FIRSTNAME, MONEY, DESCRIPTION.
I got error in this line : text1.setText(list1[position]);

```
package com.anurag.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Money extends Activity {
ArrayList list1;
TextView text1, text2, text3, text4;
ImageView iv;
ListView mList;
SQLiteDatabase db;
private static String DBNAME = "MainDB.db";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.money);
    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mList);
    list1 = new ArrayList();
    try {
        db = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from MONEY", null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            list1.add(c.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    mList.setAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

}

class MyArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom1, null);
        text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text1.setText(list1[position]);**// Problem in this line**
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

Actually i am populating data from my database and want to display in listview. Please let me know if i am writing wrong code.
Thanks

Comment: text1.setText(list1[position]);
this line shows error

Comment: what is the error post your log cat

Comment: This line of code show this error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList.
so what will be the right code should be place here.

Comment: please refer to this it shows how to use base adapter... http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-3-custom-listview/

Answer (score 2):

Change the line

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom1, null);
```

to

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom1, null);
```

and change `return null` to `return convertView`

So:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom1, null);
        text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text1.setText(list1[position]);**// Problem in this line**
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return convertView;
    }
```

Also change your getCount method to return the size of the array, so:

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list1.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to change your

```
text1.setText(list1[position]);
```

to

```
text1.setText(list1.get(position));
```

Comment: Yeah, nice catch, `list1` is an `ArrayList`, not an ordinary array.

Comment: yes i change the code but it shows : Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token

Comment: text1.setText(list1.get(position)); try like this

Comment: it shows error: The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Comment: declare your `ArrayList` like this:
`ArrayList<String> list1;` and while initializing 
`list1 = ArrayList<String>();` and consult the other answer by @JossStuart too.

Comment: This code did not show any error but i did not get list in my emulator

Comment: return v in your getView() method and return list1.size() in getCount() method